# Correctly calculating permutations and combinations without duplicate patterns

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given 16 balls each numbered 1 through 16, and 5 glass tubes numbered 1 through 5; how many ways are there to slot all 16 balls into the glass tubes, selected one at a time, with the only condition that each slot should always have at least 1 ball? The ball and glass numbers matter.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Any work done thus far?

Comment: Do you need a solution? Would a working code be of use?

Comment: @dREaM Code would work too.

Comment: Does the order of the balls in a tube matter?

Comment: @DonkeyKong I came up with if a is ball number, and glass numbers are b, then for the first 5 balls its a permutation: a!/(a - b)!, then you select one ball and have to slot it into any 5 glass tubes, so that would be (a-b)! * b^(a - b). So if I multiply the two I get a! * b^(a -b). Is this correct?

Comment: @user2566092 Yes order in which they are in the tubes matters.

Comment: @user2566092 Oh! What if the order din't matter? What is the right way to think of it then? Do you think my understanding with a! * b^(a -b) is correct?

Comment: If order within each tube doesn't matter the answer is just ${16\brace 5}\cdot 5!$ where the thing with braces is a stirling coefficient of the second kind.

Comment: @dREaM Thanks. Dint even know it was a thing! Found the wikipedia entry for Stirling coefficient of the second kind. This seems like this falls into set theory. Do you know any books that deal with this kind of set theory? I've never come across this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that order of balls in the tubes matters.

Line up the $16$ balls in some order.  There are $16!$ ways to do this. There are $15$ interball gaps. We choose $4$ of them to place a separator into in the usual Stars and Bars style. This can be done in $\binom{15}{4}$ ways.

Thus the total number of ways is $16!\binom{15}{4}$. The idea generalizes.

**Remark:** Numerically, this gives the same result as the recursion of dREaM.

Comment: Short, elegant and to the point.

Comment: Thanks! Make so much sense and so simply put. Just to make sure $\binom{15}{4}$ is a combination right? i.e. select any 4 from 15?

Comment: Yes, it is the number of ways to choose $4$ from $15$. I used the most common mathematical notation for the binomial coefficient. Some people call it $C(15,4)$, or $C_4^{15}$, or ${}_{15}C_4$, and there are other names. Numerically it is $\frac{15!}{4!11!}$ or more simply $(15)(14)(13)(12)/4!$.

Comment: Wow, this made me feel inadequate.

Comment: On the other hand, now I will make the connection in my mind between that recursion and this closed form, so it was win-win.

Comment: The recursions were good. And far more problems are solved by recursions than by closed forms.

Answer (score 2):

We can obtain a recursion.

How many ways are there to place balls $1,2,3\dots n$ in tubes $1,2,3\dots k$ so that every tube is not empty? We call this number $f(n,k)$

If we look at a proper arrangement of the balls $1,2,3\dots n-1$ then there are exactly $n+k-1$ places into which we can place the $n$'th ball (on top of any of the other $n-1$ other balls or on the bottom of any of the tubes).
This gives us $(n+k-1)f(n-1,k)$ arrangements.

The other arrangements we are missing are the arrangements in which ball $n$ is alone inside its tube, there are $k$ ways to select the tube in which it is and then $f(n-1,k-1)$ ways to fill the other tubes properly.

We have obtained the recursion $f(n,k)=(n+k-1)f(n-1,k)+kf(n-1,k-1)$.

We can use this recursion to build the following code in c++:

```
#include <cstdio>
long long factorial[17];
long long f(int n,int k){
  if(n==k){
    return(factorial[k]);
  }
  if(k==1){
    return(factorial[n]);
  }
  return((n+k-1)*f(n-1,k)+k*f(n-1,k-1));
}
int main(){
  int a;
  factorial[0]=1;
  for(a=1;a<17;a++){
    factorial[a]=factorial[a-1]*a;
  }
  printf("%lld\n",f(16,5));
}
```

It gives $28559608197120000$.